# Ionic 4: How to Suppress Click action on <ion-sliding-item> when items are open?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm using an `<ion-list>` with `<ion-sliding-item>`'s. The inner item has a `(click)` event `(click)="goToDetail(message.id)"`.

```
<ion-list #messageList>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let message of messages">
        <ion-item detail (click)="goToDetail(message.id)">
            <ion-label>
                {{ message.text }}
            </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item-options>
            <ion-item-option (click)="confirmDelete(message.id)">Delete</ion-item-option>
        </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

Normally, when the item is clicked, I want the click event to fire.

However, if I slide one of the items, revealing the 'Delete' option, then click on a different item, the sliding item closes, then the (click) event  of the other item is fired.

[image: screenshot of slider open revealing delete option]

I want to prevent this click event.  I've read the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/list#methods) and see the `<ion-list>` has a `closeSlidingItems()` method.  So, I was hoping I could simply change my click event to something like:

```
(click)="messageList.closeSlidingItems() || goToDetail(message.id)"
```

But, the closeSlidingItems() method returns a promise, not a boolean.  Okay, no problem, I thought to just wrap my `goToDetail()` function with this check.

```
public goToDetail(threadId) {
    this.messageList.closeSlidingItems()
        .then(sliderWasClosed => {
            if (!sliderWasClosed) {
                this.nav.navigateForward('app/conversation/' + threadId);
            }
        });
}
```

However, what I'm finding is that the promise always returns `false`, even when a sliding item is in fact closed.  I suspect this is because the close operation happens automatically and by the time my function is called, the item is already closed.

My overall goal is to prevent the `(click)` event when sliders are open.  My current code would work if the `closeSlidingItems()` method would return the proper value.

Is there a way I can prevent this automatic closing of sliding items in order to get the correct result when I call `closeSlidingItems()` myself?

Is there another event I should be using besides `(click)` ?

Any other ideas how I can get this to work?

[StackBlitz of issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-close-sliding-items-always-returns-false-on-click)

Comment: It clarify you problem is what exactly? which click event are your wanting to stop ?

Comment: @IraW I'm trying to prevent the click event on any <ion-item> whenever any slider item is open.  I suppose I don't really need to suppress the click event, but I want to have different behaviors depending on if ANY slider item is in the open position.

Comment: I'd add a class that applys `pointer-events: none;` to the other items when one is open.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `false` because the context is wrong when you click.

> closeSlidingItems() Returns true if an **actual** ion-item-sliding is
>   closed

Here is a method from [docs](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/e5c8c10029d5211717e25057afb4c34cb7b7523c/core/src/components/list/list.tsx):

```
  async closeSlidingItems(): Promise<boolean> {
    const item = this.el.querySelector('ion-item-sliding');
    if (item && item.closeOpened) {
      return item.closeOpened();
    }
    return false;
  }
```

`this.el.querySelector('ion-item-sliding')` gives you only the first matching `ion-item-sliding` in `this` context. And it is not the same which is currently open (because you cick on the different `ion-item-sliding`).

So there is no default way, AFAIK, to do what you want. However, IonItemSliding component exposes `ionDrag` event, which is triggered when you slide the item. That event has `detail.ratio` property, which becomes `1` when `ion-item-options` is open. So you could relay on this, by reseting `ration` value every time you click `goToDetail()`.

```
<ion-item-sliding (ionDrag)="dragEvent($event.detail.ratio)" *ngFor="let message of messages">
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I may try utilizing the `(ionDrag)`.  I will mention that I don't think the context is necessarily wrong.  If trigger my `goToDetail()` method from a button (rather than a ion-list click event), the `.closeSlidingItems()` call does return the correct true or false value based on the whether or not a sliding item was open.

Comment: No, it is impossible to get `true` if you click on other menu item which is not open. I posted a method from source code. The context of `this` comes from the click event. Click event happens on one menu item and you see what happens later in that method. Provide a stackblitz or share your code, I could explain then

Comment: Maybe that's not the code that's being hit or there is more code being hit.  I'm definitely getting back 'true' when any slider is open when I call that function from anywhere other than the ion-item (click).  Further, that's what the documentation says it should return.

Anyway, I was able to work around this by using your suggestion of using ionDrag.  So thanks for that!

Comment: Not sure about your case, if you provide your code, I could look into it, but I made word **actual** bold for a reason. You miss this word in docs and you misunderstand the meaning of this method. If you get true when you call method from somewhere else, it still means that the context is the exact menu item, which is currently open. Feel free to provide some code if need any help on Ionic

Comment: here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-close-sliding-items-always-returns-false-on-click) demonstrating the behavior I described.  

To reproduce GOOD behavior: 1) Slide an item open 2) click the button 3) RESULT: item is closed && log message indicates item was closed.

To reproduce BAD behavior: 1) Slide an item open 2) click a different item 3) RESULT: item is closed && log message indicates item was NOT closed

Notice both click events fire the same `closeOpenItems()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Hei guys

`<ion-item-sliding #itemSliding *ngFor="elemets..." (touchmove)="itemSliding.open('end');">`

this is the solution :)